# Prove division of two quadratics has a value at a zero of the divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm helping my son with high school questions. The question was to simplify this:

$\frac{3x^2-8x-3}{2x^2-6x}$

With a bit of factoring and cancelling we got to the following, which was marked as correct.

$\frac{3x+1}{2x}$

But what about the value at x=3 ? From the first version of the formula it gives:

$\frac{27 - 24 - 3}{18-18} = \frac{0}{0}$

Surely that is not defined?

The second version of the formula gives:

$\frac{9+1}6 = \frac{10}6$

Comment: The original is undefined at $x=3$.  The reduced form is defined at $x=3$ and that tells us that the original was "well behaved" near $x=3$.  A simpler example of the same phenomenon is $f(x)=\frac xx$.  That is undefined at $0$, though of course it equals $1$ for all non-zero $x$.

Comment: @lulu, so are the two formulae equal to each other?

Comment: Not equal. Recommend you get some graph paper and plot a bunch of points; you can download and print pdf's of graph paper. With your involvement, graphing by hand might actually happen. The ability to visualize comes from the student drawing things, not from staring at a computer generated graph.  https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: They are equal wherever both are defined.  $\frac xx=1$ except when $x=0$.

Comment: Note that 2x^2-6x = 2x(x-3). 3x^2-8x-3 = (3x+1)(x-3). You are allowed to cancel out x-3 from the numerator and denominator as long as x is not equal to 3. Or in other words the second formula equals the first for all values of x except x = 3. As you've said the first formula is undefined for x=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplification is right. And yes, undefined at $3$ for original, and simplified version is $10/6$ [same as $5/3$]. Its the same phenomenon as $x/x=1$ which gives $0/0$ at $x=0$ [undefined] and $1$ at $x=1.$